# Android Studio emulator not starting when I run the project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

It was working fine until today. When I clicked run button, emulator selection tab was showing up and I could choose an emulator to try my project. But today, when I click run button, emulator selection screen doesn't show up.

Instead of opening emulator, it executes task 'signingReport' at Run tab at the bottom of screen. I only added the option of Google sign-in and copied a code from this 'signingReport' tab yesterday if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is very simple just go to the tab right side of the build icon in android studio and [image: where it is written pedometer-master 2]

then click on project name and run.it will work fine.please upvote the answer if it was helpful

Comment: Since I couldn't open the image you provided, I couldn't clearly understood which tab you are referring. Can you send it again from another link than Imgur, or can you be more specific about the place of that tab? I am new at android studio, so I don't know which tab is where. Sorry about that.

Comment: ok no problem.just click on the tab next to build icon(hammer icon).in that tab a android pic will be there with your project name.